# WIX customAction Checkbox

Tags: wix

I am try to use Checkbox with this sample from WIX

nothing happened when I try to use the Checkbox

Regards

```
<Binary Id="StringTransfer" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)CustomAction2\bin\Release\CustomAction2.CA.dll" />
<CustomAction
  Id="INSTALLSETTINGS"
  BinaryKey="StringTransfer"
  DllEntry="CustomAction1"
  Execute="deferred"
  Impersonate="no"
  Return="check"
/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="INSTALLSETTINGS" After="InstallInitialize">
    CHECKBOXINSTALLSETTINGS=1
  </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>


    <Control Id="test" Type="CheckBox"  Width="125" Height="26" X="26" Y="124" Text="My text" Property="CHECKBOXINSTALLSETTINGS" CheckBoxValue="1" />

<Property Id="CHECKBOXINSTALLSETTINGS" Value="1"/>
```

<CustomAction()>
Public Shared Function CustomAction1(ByVal session As Session) As ActionResult

```
    My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\VB and VBA Program Settings\Test", "mintext", "0")

    session.Log("Begin CustomAction1")

    Return ActionResult.Success
End Function
```

Comment: [Maybe this sample with a check box to open the log file for the MSI installation](https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXOpenLogFile) could be helpful?

Comment: Hi This url worked

Comment: Great, [maybe have a quick look here too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67902133/129130).